# Set As Homepage On Android Browser

Tags: android, browser

Is there a script for the Android Webkit browser thats make a site "homepage"
Or in other words can I make a "Set as homepage" button

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a method to do that. It would be on `android.provider.Browser`, if anywhere. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

struggling with reading the homepage myself right now. Writing it will use the std database stuff, my book mark writer has something like this in it:

{final ContentValues bookmarkValues = new ContentValues();
      bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, pageTitle);
      bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, currentUrl);
      bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      final Uri newBookmark = getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, bookmarkValues);}

```
  So writing the home page will probably use some similar construct.
```